# Ubuntu GRUB is replaced by Fedora GRUB2

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I had upgraded kernel of Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and Fedora 18 to the latest update. I had updated the Ubuntu's GRUB with command

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

When i updated the grub, I had mounted Fedora's partition. However, Fedora's GRUB2 take over bootloader.

How should i do to make Ubuntu's GRUB taking over the bootloader?

Answer (score 1):

Boot into ubuntu

Add repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

Install boot repair

```
Sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Then run boot-repair from terminal

This might work. At least its something to try. It should launch a gui giving you options to help you fix grub. Its quite easy to use and self explanatry

```
boot-repair
```

Comment: thank you, is there any risk using boot-repair?

Comment: I suppose there is a small risk, but im pretty much a noob and ive used it lots of times and if it has fixed a number of issues for me on a number of occasions. I think there is option to reinstall grub there. That option should be safe. I think its quite obvious if your gonna do something risky in the utility. E.g. mucking arround with the master boot records etc....

Comment: i am just afraid if i have to upgrade all my distros. that means maybe boot configurations have changed and boot-repair doens't always update with new configurations

Comment: If u changed configs run boot-repair again if its not working. Everytime u upgrade a distro, I think that it will overwrite grub with its own version. Some distros let you choose not to install the grub and give u options on overwritting the mbr. May e google how to upgrade distro without affecting the mbr. Or edit ur question to ask this

Comment: if your really worried your gonna screw it all up make your self a super grub boot cd. This purpose of the disk is "if theres an OS on your HDDs, this will find it and allow you to log into it" even if youve screwed up your MBR a little bit. So just make urself one of these as a safetynet http://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`.

Comment: thank you, what is command for?

Comment: @obysr, to have Ubuntu's grub take back over of course?

Comment: that command needs some configs that i've never known. Can you explain it?

Comment: @obysr, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: ok, having typed sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc, it appears some dialogs in terminal. How should I do with them?

Comment: @obysr, that isn't any more specific; *what* is the question you are being asked that you don't understand?